# Autofac: How to pass parameters to register in a razor page

Tags: c#, autofac, razor-pages

I am injecting an HttpClient to the Razor Page. The HttpClient needs three parameters, username, password, and serverAddress. During registration, I provide the serverAddress.

```
builder.RegisterType<HttpClient>().As<IHttpClient>()
            .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
                        (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(string) && 
                        pi.Name == "serverAddress",
                        (pi, ctx) => "https://server.address.com"));
```

However, I can only provide username and password after the user logins in a Razor Page. How can I pass the username and password to the HttpClient register?

---

John's answered solved my problem. Now, I have a follow up question. Once, I pass the parameter from the Razor page, how can I make the other classes depend on the HttpClient pick up the user information automatically? So now things look like this,

```
builder.RegisterType<HttpClient>().As<IHttpClient>()
            .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
                        (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(string) && 
                        pi.Name == "serverAddress",
                        (pi, ctx) => "https://server.address.com"));

builder.Register(HttpClientFactory)
            .As<Func<string, string, IHttpClient>>();

builder.RegisterType<Bamboo>().As<IBamboo>();
```

where Bamboo depends on IHttpClient to communicate with the Bamboo server.

For the second part of the question, I believe I can create a constructor for the Bamboo class and make it take two parameters of username and password. Then, I can create a Func<> and register it for the Bamboo class. However, I am curious about whether I can update the information in the HttpClient and make the other classes depend on it pick up the user information automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few approaches to this depending on exactly where your client credentials need to come from, but the simplest and most flexible option is probably just to inject some form of factory which you can use at run-time. That could be done with a custom factory class, but if you want to give maximum flexibility with dependencies on your HttpClient without requiring references to Autofac further down the call-stack, you can do it using a `Func<>` like this:

```
private static Func<string, string, IHttpClient> GetHttpClientFactory(IComponentContext c)
{
    var context = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
    return (u, p) => context.Resolve<IHttpClient>(new NamedParameter("username", u), new NamedParameter("password", p));
}

...

builder.RegisterType<HttpClient>()
    .As<IHttpClient>()
    .WithParameter(new NamedParameter("serverAddress", "https://server.address.com"));

builder.Register(GetHttpClientFactory)
    .As<Func<string, string, IHttpClient>>();
```

Your usage might then look something like this:

```
public class Page
{
    private readonly Func<string, string, IHttpClient> _httpClientFactory;

    public Page(Func<string, string, IHttpClient> httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public void DoHttpStuff()
    {
        // extract the user http credentials from the logged-in identity here / handle cases where they're not available:
        var user = "SomeUser";
        var password = "SomePassword";
        var client = _httpClientFactory(user, password);
        // use the client
    }
}
```

There are ways you could take this further and try to read the http credentials from the user context as part of the Autofac registration but it probably just adds a lot of unnecessary complication if something like the above works for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks John. I have a follow up question. Where should I put the Func<>? In the HttpClient class or with the registration. I am not quite familiar with Func<> yet.

Comment: I tested it and it works. I created a Func<> in the Autofac Module class for the HttpClient. In the Load() function I register the Func<> as John described.

Comment: No problem - could you mark this as answered? Thanks.